# Find No.of days between two dates (Tuples)

Tags: python, date

Suppose I have a tuple A. It contains two nested tuples. The nested tuples are dates of the form DD,MM,YYYY.

`A = ((DD,MM,YYYY), (DD,MM,YYYY))`

Now, I want to find the number of days between the two dates. I've already tried fiddling with `datetime` module and it only helps when objects are integers and not tuples. My problem constraint is that I cannot change the structure in which dates are represented. I suppose I can use slicing but that would be way too much work. I'm pretty new at this and I hope someone can shed some light my way.

Comment: Read [converting-string-into-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to create a `datetime` object from the given string. Then you can subtract `date1` and `date2` which gives you a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object and this `timedelta` object has a nice attribute `days` which gives you the number of days between two dates.

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime("-".join(A[0]), "%d-%m-%Y")
date2 = datetime.strptime("-".join(A[1]), "%d-%m-%Y")
diff_days = (date1 - date2).days

print(diff_days)
```

For example consider,

`A = (("24","05","2020"), ("25","04","2020"))` then the above code will print `diff_days` as `29`.

Answer (score 1):

Code written on my smartphone. Basic idea convert with datetime and a f string to datetime object within a list comprehension. Build the timedelta and finally get the result in different formats

```
A=((3,4,2000), (4,4,2000))

from datetime import datetime

dt = [datetime.strptime(f'{a[0]}.{a[1]}.{a[2]}','%d.%m.%Y') for a in A]
td = dt[1] - dt[0]

# when you want a tuple w only days
difference_tuple = (td.days)

# days, hours, minutes
days, hours, minutes = td.days, td.seconds // 3600, td.seconds // 60 % 60
difference_tuple2 = (days, hours, minutes)
```

Answer (score 1):

why is slicing too much work?

```
import datetime

# A = ((DD,MM,YYYY), (DD,MM,YYYY))

A = ((1,1,2020), (20,4,2020))

delta = (
    datetime.date(A[1][2],A[1][1],A[1][0])-
    datetime.date(A[0][2],A[0][1],A[0][0])
)
```